# SSL Seal Broken with everything https on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I moved my wordpress website to https and all the images are called using https however when I run whynopadlock.com it tells me my images are called using http. 
URL is https://www.ambitomujer.com.ar/10-formas-de-darte-cuenta-si-es-el-hombre-indicado/

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't solve it so I decided to activate jetpack images which solved it by using wp.com server to host images